# multiple joins on same tables

Tags: mysql, sql

So far I have this.

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p1.real_name, p2.player_id, p2.real_name,
    ->      m.scoreA, m.scoreB
    -> FROM matches m
    -> JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
    -> JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB;
+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| player_id | real_name                          | player_id | real_name                          | scoreA | scoreB |
+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|        19 | Seong Hun Choi                     |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|        38 | Yun Sik Choi                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|       160 | Lei Wang                           |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|         3 | Seung Hyun Lee                     |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|        45 | Min Chul Kim                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|        23 | Sasha Hostyn                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      2 |      4 |
|        52 | Juan Moreno Duran                  |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      2 |      3 |
|        18 | Kang Dong Hyun                     |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      2 |      1 |
|        22 | Jae Duck Lim                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      1 |      2 |
|       108 | JÃ©rÃ©my Vansnick                  |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      1 |      2 |
```

I would like to join a few more columns from my `members` table without changing the size of my matches `table`. Everything I try seems to change the size of my matches table. It goes from 46k to over 1 million. This is what I have tried so far.

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p1.real_name, p2.player_id, p2.real_name, 
     m.scoreA, m.scoreB, mem1.player, mem2.player
FROM matches m
JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
JOIN members mem1 ON mem1.player = p1.player_id
JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB
JOIN members mem2 ON mem2.player = p2.player_id;
```

I thought maybe I was setting the equal part wrong so then I tried this.

```
SELECT p1.player_id, p1.real_name, p2.player_id, p2.real_name, 
     m.scoreA, m.scoreB, mem1.player, mem2.player
FROM matches m
JOIN players p1 ON p1.player_id = m.playerA
JOIN members mem1 ON mem1.player = m.playerA
JOIN players p2 ON p2.player_id = m.playerB
JOIN members mem2 ON mem2.player = m.playerB;
```

I would like it to look something like this when it is finished.

```
    +-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+
| player_id | real_name                          | player_id | real_name                          | scoreA | scoreB |  member1     member2
+-----------+------------------------------------+-----------+------------------------------------+--------+--------+
|        19 | Seong Hun Choi                     |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|        38 | Yun Sik Choi                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|       160 | Lei Wang                           |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|         3 | Seung Hyun Lee                     |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|        45 | Min Chul Kim                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
|        23 | Sasha Hostyn                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      2 |      4 |
|        52 | Juan Moreno Duran                  |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      2 |      3 |
|        18 | Kang Dong Hyun                     |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      2 |      1 |
|        22 | Jae Duck Lim                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      1 |      2 |
|       108 | JÃ©rÃ©my Vansnick                  |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      1 |      2 |
|        53 | Igor Turchin                       |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      1 |      2 |
|        17 | Hyun Woo Park                      |         1 | Dong Nyoung Lee                    |      0 |      2 |
```

I also need to repeat this process with two more tables so helping me understand the procedure of how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

---

Matches table.

```
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
| match_id | date       | tournament | playerA | playerB | scoreA | scoreB | offline |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
|        1 | 2012-12-04 |        799 |       4 |      55 |      1 |      3 |       0 |
|        2 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |       2 |      41 |      2 |      0 |       0 |
|        3 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      21 |      41 |      0 |      2 |       0 |
|        4 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |       3 |       2 |      2 |      1 |       0 |
|        5 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      41 |       2 |      1 |      2 |       0 |
|        6 | 2012-12-03 |      11921 |      21 |       3 |      1 |      2 |       0 |
|        7 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      1 |       1 |
|        8 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       1 |       8 |      2 |      3 |       1 |
|        9 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |       8 |      19 |      3 |      2 |       1 |
|       10 | 2012-12-03 |      11924 |      19 |      12 |      2 |      1 |       1 |
+----------+------------+------------+---------+---------+--------+--------+---------+
```

Players table

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
| player_id | tag       | real_name       | nationality | birthday   | game_race |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
|         1 | Leenock   | Dong Nyoung Lee | KR          | 1995-04-01 | Z         |
|         2 | Creator   | Hyun Woo Jang   | KR          | 1996-08-19 | P         |
|         3 | Life      | Seung Hyun Lee  | KR          | 1997-01-11 | Z         |
|         4 | DongRaeGu | Soo Ho Park     | KR          | 1991-06-03 | Z         |
|         5 | PartinG   | Lee Sak Won     | KR          | 1994-08-24 | P         |
|         6 | TaeJa     | Young Suh Yoon  | KR          | 1995-01-01 | T         |
|         7 | Rain      | Yoon Jong Jung  | KR          | 1992-08-14 | P         |
|         8 | viOLet    | Dong Hwan Kim   | KR          | 1990-12-05 | Z         |
|         9 | Sniper    | Tae Hoon Kwon   | KR          | 1995-01-22 | Z         |
|        10 | Stephano  | Ilyes Satouri   | FR          | 1993-03-12 | Z         |
+-----------+-----------+-----------------+-------------+------------+-----------+
```

members table

```
+--------+------+------------+------------+
| player | team | start_date | end_date   |
+--------+------+------------+------------+
|      1 |   88 | 2011-02-23 | 2011-07-18 |
|      1 |    4 | 2011-07-18 | NULL       |
|      2 |    3 | 2011-01-12 | NULL       |
|      3 |   65 | 2010-10-19 | 2012-07-13 |
|      3 |    1 | 2012-07-13 | NULL       |
|      4 |    7 | 2011-02-20 | NULL       |
|      5 |   88 | 2010-10-29 | 2011-07-18 |
|      5 |    1 | 2012-10-21 | 2013-01-03 |
|      5 |   12 | 2013-01-14 | NULL       |
|      6 |   65 | 2011-03-01 | 2011-05-01 |
+--------+------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Can you write the schema here?

Comment: don't display the results of multi-table queries, instead show us some data from each table. including the DDL of each table would help too.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `player_id | real_name | player_id | real_name | scoreA | scoreB | member1 member2` I am sorry I don't know what you mean by schema.

Comment: just show **a few rows** (with headings) from **each table**. this will help us. Include it into the question (not here as a comment, and not images please) **not rows from multi-table queries**

Comment: @Used_By_Already Done. Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query is generating a semi-Cartesian product.

`player` column is not unique in the `member` table. It looks like a `player` is a `member` of only one team at a time, based on the `start_date` and `end_date`.

We probably want to include a comparison of the `date` from the `match` table to the `start_date` and `end_date` in `member` table.  We might also want to make it an outer join.

```
LEFT
JOIN `member` mem2
  ON mem2.player      = m.playerB
 AND mem2.start_date <= m.date
 AND ( mem2.end_date >  m.date OR mem2.end_date IS NULL )
```

Note that one of the date comparisons includes an equality, the other side doesn't (because the `start_date` on row appears to be equal to the `end_date` on another row in `member`, for the same for the same `player`.

(For a match `date='2011-07-18'`, which team was `player=1` a member of?)

We also want to handle the `NULL` value in `end_date`, in this case, having that represent a large value that is greater than the `match` `date`.

We want to use the same pattern for `mem1` as well.

Comment: How do I get better at finding these problems? I have been staring this most of the day and couldn't figure it out. I figured I could address the date issue after I set up my joins.

Comment: when i'm building queries like this, i put the PRIMARY or UNIQUE key columns of each table at the beginning of the select list, and order by those same primary key columns.  The key to avoiding duplicate is identifying the guaranteed cardinality  of the relationships...  I need to know if it's guaranteed to be one to one,  or  one to zero-or-one,  or one to zero-one-or-many,  or many to many.

Answer (score 1):

There is an initial problem in the way your matches table is constructed. Consider the following which "flips" each player and score into a single row of their own. Now the number of subsequent joins is instantly halved:

```
  select
        piv, match_id, date, tournament, offline
      , case when piv = 1 then playerA 
             else playerB 
        end as Player_id
      , case when piv = 1 then scoreA 
             else scoreB 
        end as Score
  from matches
  cross join (select 1 as piv union all select 2) cj
```

10 rows in the matches table becomes 20 rows from that query:

```
| piv | match_id |                 date | tournament | offline | Player_id | Score |
|-----|----------|----------------------|------------|---------|-----------|-------|
|   1 |        1 | 2012-12-04T00:00:00Z |        799 |       0 |         4 |     1 |
|   2 |        1 | 2012-12-04T00:00:00Z |        799 |       0 |        55 |     3 |
|   1 |        2 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         2 |     2 |
|   2 |        2 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        41 |     0 |
|   1 |        3 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        21 |     0 |
|   2 |        3 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        41 |     2 |
|   1 |        4 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         3 |     2 |
|   2 |        4 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         2 |     1 |
|   1 |        5 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        41 |     1 |
|   2 |        5 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         2 |     2 |
|   1 |        6 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        21 |     1 |
|   2 |        6 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         3 |     2 |
|   1 |        7 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         1 |     2 |
|   2 |        7 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         8 |     1 |
|   1 |        8 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         1 |     2 |
|   2 |        8 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         8 |     3 |
|   1 |        9 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         8 |     3 |
|   2 |        9 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |        19 |     2 |
|   1 |       10 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |        19 |     2 |
|   2 |       10 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |        12 |     1 |
```

So, using that as a starting point the joining to players data is dead simple, and while it is also simple for the members table as well, we do want to ensure we only get their "current" row from that table so we place today's date between the start/end dates of each team (today's date is used if the end date is NULL).

```
select
*
from (
      select
            piv, match_id, date, tournament, offline
          , case when piv = 1 then playerA 
                 else playerB 
            end as Player_id
          , case when piv = 1 then scoreA 
                 else scoreB 
            end as Score
      from matches
      cross join (select 1 as piv union all select 2) cj
     ) g
left join Players p on g.Player_id = p.Player_id
left join Members m on g.Player_id = m.player 
                    and curdate() between m.start_date and coalesce(m.end_date,curdate())
```

This produces NO further increase in the 20 rows:

```
| piv | match_id |                 date | tournament | offline | Player_id | Score | player_id |       tag |       real_name | nationality |             birthday | game_race | player |   team |           start_date | end_date |
|-----|----------|----------------------|------------|---------|-----------|-------|-----------|-----------|-----------------|-------------|----------------------|-----------|--------|--------|----------------------|----------|
|   1 |        7 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         1 |     2 |         1 |   Leenock | Dong Nyoung Lee |          KR | 1995-04-01T00:00:00Z |         Z |      1 |      4 | 2011-07-18T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   1 |        8 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         1 |     2 |         1 |   Leenock | Dong Nyoung Lee |          KR | 1995-04-01T00:00:00Z |         Z |      1 |      4 | 2011-07-18T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   1 |        2 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         2 |     2 |         2 |   Creator |   Hyun Woo Jang |          KR | 1996-08-19T00:00:00Z |         P |      2 |      3 | 2011-01-12T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   2 |        4 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         2 |     1 |         2 |   Creator |   Hyun Woo Jang |          KR | 1996-08-19T00:00:00Z |         P |      2 |      3 | 2011-01-12T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   2 |        5 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         2 |     2 |         2 |   Creator |   Hyun Woo Jang |          KR | 1996-08-19T00:00:00Z |         P |      2 |      3 | 2011-01-12T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   1 |        4 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         3 |     2 |         3 |      Life |  Seung Hyun Lee |          KR | 1997-01-11T00:00:00Z |         Z |      3 |      1 | 2012-07-13T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   2 |        6 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |         3 |     2 |         3 |      Life |  Seung Hyun Lee |          KR | 1997-01-11T00:00:00Z |         Z |      3 |      1 | 2012-07-13T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   1 |        1 | 2012-12-04T00:00:00Z |        799 |       0 |         4 |     1 |         4 | DongRaeGu |     Soo Ho Park |          KR | 1991-06-03T00:00:00Z |         Z |      4 |      7 | 2011-02-20T00:00:00Z |   (null) |
|   2 |        7 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         8 |     1 |         8 |    viOLet |   Dong Hwan Kim |          KR | 1990-12-05T00:00:00Z |         Z | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   2 |        8 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         8 |     3 |         8 |    viOLet |   Dong Hwan Kim |          KR | 1990-12-05T00:00:00Z |         Z | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   1 |        9 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |         8 |     3 |         8 |    viOLet |   Dong Hwan Kim |          KR | 1990-12-05T00:00:00Z |         Z | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   2 |        1 | 2012-12-04T00:00:00Z |        799 |       0 |        55 |     3 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   2 |        2 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        41 |     0 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   1 |        3 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        21 |     0 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   2 |        3 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        41 |     2 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   1 |        5 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        41 |     1 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   1 |        6 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |       0 |        21 |     1 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   2 |        9 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |        19 |     2 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   1 |       10 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |        19 |     2 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
|   2 |       10 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |       1 |        12 |     1 |    (null) |    (null) |          (null) |      (null) |               (null) |    (null) | (null) | (null) |               (null) |   (null) |
```

[SQLfiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e8555d/7)

nb: To revert back to a pivoted view of the information:

```
select
      match_id, match_date, tournament
    , max(case when piv = 1 then real_name end) PlayerAreal_name
    , max(case when piv = 1 then player_Id end) PlayerA
    , max(case when piv = 1 then player_Id end) ScoreA

    , max(case when piv = 2 then real_name end) PlayerBreal_name
    , max(case when piv = 2 then player_Id end) PlayerB
    , max(case when piv = 2 then player_Id end) Scoreb
from (
       the big query above goes here
     )
group by 
  match_id, match_date, tournament
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/419277/1)

```
| match_id |           match_date | tournament | PlayerAreal_name | PlayerA | ScoreA | PlayerBreal_name | PlayerB | Scoreb |
|----------|----------------------|------------|------------------|---------|--------|------------------|---------|--------|
|        1 | 2012-12-04T00:00:00Z |        799 |      Soo Ho Park |       4 |      4 |           (null) |      55 |     55 |
|        2 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |    Hyun Woo Jang |       2 |      2 |           (null) |      41 |     41 |
|        3 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |           (null) |      21 |     21 |           (null) |      41 |     41 |
|        4 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |   Seung Hyun Lee |       3 |      3 |    Hyun Woo Jang |       2 |      2 |
|        5 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |           (null) |      41 |     41 |    Hyun Woo Jang |       2 |      2 |
|        6 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11921 |           (null) |      21 |     21 |   Seung Hyun Lee |       3 |      3 |
|        7 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |  Dong Nyoung Lee |       1 |      1 |    Dong Hwan Kim |       8 |      8 |
|        8 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |  Dong Nyoung Lee |       1 |      1 |    Dong Hwan Kim |       8 |      8 |
|        9 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |    Dong Hwan Kim |       8 |      8 |           (null) |      19 |     19 |
|       10 | 2012-12-03T00:00:00Z |      11924 |           (null) |      19 |     19 |           (null) |      12 |     12 |
```

Comment: Can you please help me understand this? I don't understand what piv is or where it comes from and how its generated. I assume the reason the records doubles from 47k to 92k is you are putting each player on there own line right? How do cross joins work? I have never used them. Is the `cj` at the end of this short for cross join `cross join (select 1 as piv union all select 2) cj`?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` places the rows together without condition (in effect it multiples the rows).  is cj = cross join = YES. "piv" is just a column name I plucked from thin air, short for pivot. It is "generated" by `select 1 as piv union all select 2`, try it, it just outputs 2 rows. "*the reason the records doubles from 47k to 92k is you are putting each player on there own line right?*" = YES